# can Telegram Bot sends message to group?

Tags: telegram-bot

I create a group on Telegram and created a bot and add in.

I am trying to send a message to group that I created and the error shown as below

**{"ok":false,"error_code":403,"description":"[Error]: Forbidden: can't write to chat with deleted user"}**

I have use **getUpdates** from Bot Documents and managed to get chat id and doesn't work again for me. p2p (private type message) works for me but not group type.

Any advice please? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can, you have to invite the bot into the group, grab the `chat_id` of the group and send the message as you are sending a normal message to a private user.

The error message is self-explanatory tough.

Comment: {"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":85510588, "message":{"message_id":2,"from":{"id":26236173,"first_name":"Farhan","last_name":"Kamarzaman","username":"farhankamar"},"chat":{"id":26236173,"first_name":"Farhan","last_name":"Kamarzaman","username":"farhankamar","type":"private"},"date":1435471096,"text":"he...
----

{"ok":false,"error_code":403,"description":"[Error]: Forbidden: can't write to chat with deleted user"}



Something like this and still received ERROR message live above

Comment: Create a new group with the bot and try again.

`[Error]: Forbidden: can't write to chat with deleted user` it seems there is a deleted user in this group.

Comment: thank you i got it worked, I overlooked at chat id, there are negative at beginning number for group chat. thank you :)